# Fetch JSON data using YQL for Facebook

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, yql

I want to know how to fetch the JSON data using [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/).

This is my JSON URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json
```

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/ in here .i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heres a quick example using jQuery, it might help you out

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.query.results.json);
            $.each(data.query.results.json.entries, function (i, v) {
                //console.log(data.query.results.json.entries[i]);
                $('#entries').append(data.query.results.json.entries[i].title + '<br />');
            });
        }, data: {
            q: 'select * from json where url="https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json"',
            format: "json"
        }
    });
});
```

Inside the console.log with the above url I was able to get back the following results:

```
entries: Array[29]
icon: "http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico"
link: "http://www.facebook.com/"
self: "https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=397319800348866&format=json"
title: "Doers Inc's Facebook Wall"
updated: "2012-12-19T01:08:44-08:00"
```

Working example for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/DtNxb/1/

Comment: The result only show up if you look at them in your browsers console.

Comment: can you correct it work with the html output ?

Comment: I updated it to show you the entries titles. You should be able to figure the rest out from there

Comment: one question : why that title showing half ?

Comment: It seems like facebook is truncating the titles to around 85 characters. If the title is less than a certain amount of characters they are appending characters out of the contents field.

Comment: Instead of using `.title` use `.content` to get the full title along with images too. [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DtNxb/6/)

Answer (score 2):

It's easier than you think if you use [jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22your_url&format=json",
          function(data) {
              var id = data.query.results.div;
              $('#table').append('<li>'+id.h1+'</li>');
              $('#table').listview('refresh');
          }
);
```

**[A simple demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xu2FJ/)**

Comment: what about my given url ? can you make a fiddle using my given url ?

Comment: @sami: **Steven Farley** has already done that...

Comment: @arttronics: Yes, if the URL includes the string `"callback=?"` in the URL, the request is treated as JSONP instead. Here's an [example](http://www.tbogard.com/2008/05/31/tutorial-how-to-jsonp-with-jquery-using-getjson-or-ajax/)